# How to detect - is webstorage enabled in client web browser?

Tags: javascript, angular, html

I've Angular app which needs webstorage (in my case sessionstorage) to work correct. I need to check users web browser settings to avoid launch app when it's disabled. How to check it using the best method?

I found this site:

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/localstorage-pattern

but release data is really old, so I would ask, is it still good way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it simply like this :

```
if (window.localStorage){
// the user's browser supports localStorage
}
```

Comment: Simple solution are the best :). Thank You!